# Issue saving Map to File in Java

Tags: java, file, encryption, save, maps

I have two maps that get generated just fine. 
Now I want to stop generating them and work from a file.

The map structure is

```
private Map<String, List<Integer>> codebook = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();
private Map<Integer, String> decodebook = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
```

Below is the code I am using for saving and loading.
The decodebook seems to work just fine, it is the codebook
I can not seem to load back to program. I am afraid seen 
as I am working with a Objects it is difficult to tell if it 
is even saving correctly.

I run the program once and this code will run be run with it.

```
try {
        saveCodeBook(codebook, "CodeBook");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {

        saveDecodeBook(decodebook, "DecodeBook");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}



public void saveCodeBook(Map<String, List<Integer>> obj,
        String filePath) throws IOException {
    OutputStream os = null;
    try {
        os = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath));

        ((ObjectOutputStream) os).writeObject(obj);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    } finally {
        os.close();
    }
}

public void saveDecodeBook(Map<Integer,String> obj,
        String filePath) throws IOException {
    OutputStream os = null;
    try {
        os = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath));

        ((ObjectOutputStream) os).writeObject(obj);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    } finally {
        os.close();
    }
}
```

The second time I run the program, I comment out above code.
(NOT THIS Piece directly below, this is always left)

```
private Map<String, List<Integer>> codebook = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();
private Map<Integer, String> decodebook = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
```

Ok once above code is removed, I run the program again, with this code included.

```
public void loadBooks() throws IOException{

    loadCodeBook("CodeBook");
    //System.out.println(codebook);


    loadDeCodeBook("DecodeBook");
    //System.out.println(codebook);
    System.out.println(decodebook);

}

public Map<String, List<Integer>> loadCodeBook(String filePath)
        throws IOException {
    HashMap<String, List<Integer>> codebook = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filePath));
        codebook = (HashMap<String, List<Integer>>) ((ObjectInputStream) is)
                .readObject();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    } finally {
        is.close();
    }
    return this.codebook = codebook;
}
public Map<Integer, String> loadDeCodeBook(String filePath)
        throws IOException {
    HashMap<Integer,String> decodebook = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filePath));
        decodebook = (HashMap<Integer, String>) ((ObjectInputStream) is)
                .readObject();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    } finally {
        is.close();
    }
    return this.decodebook = decodebook;
}
```

It seems the decodebook will work.
For about codebook I just get returned a null.

I was wondering if anyone can spot the problem? & if not thanks for trying.

Comment: Just to be clear when I generate the codebooks in the program and work from the Maps it works just fine, its just writing and reading, too and from the file I have the problem.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, is it throwing an exception of some kind? (ClassCast/NullPointer seem to be some possibilities) or is it returning a set full of corrupt data or an empty map?

Comment: the program as you can see populates a Map of <String, List<Integer>>; this works fine when I am not working with the files. If I work with the file, the program runs under the covers, no exceptions been throw. The problem is it does not populate the Map. When I do a system out after loadCodeBook("CodeBook"); It prints out null (no brackets of any kind[],{}) when I do the System.out.println(decodebook); it prints out what is expected {10047=mile, 10046=like, 10045=on,....etc

Comment: Hmm I've just tried to run your code, and codebook didn't return null for me... I've added an entry to codebook using the following code : `codebook.put("test",new ArrayList<Integer>());`.. After saving and loading it from file I obtained the following output: `{test=[]}` which is expected because the array list is empty..

Comment: i run my program, it populates codebook perfectly, it happens in stages. There is 900 separate keys in codebook, each of them have 1000 values in the linked list. So then once this part runs, i call the saveCookBook(codebook, "CodeBook"); It builds the file, from the Map. I was getting tired, and did not try mini tests, will do tomorrow.

Comment: maybe its the fact you used ArrayList<Integer> rather than List<integer>, again will try tomorrow, night.

Comment: @serhiy in a way your solution allowed for the solution to be found, so thank you.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22879469/issue-saving-and-loading-to-from-file-in-java/22880519?noredirect=1#22880519

Comment: this is the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22879469/issue-saving-and-loading-to-from-file-in-java/22880519?noredirect=1#22880519

Comment: When saving to a file using Object Streams, you need always to see if the object you are saving do implement Serializable. If you check Java documentation you can see that List is an interface which cannot implements any other interface/object. While ArrayList is an implementation of the List, which implements Serializable. Paying a bit more attention to documents will save you a lot of time ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I THOUGHT THIS WAS BEGINNING TO GET A BIT BUSY SO POSTED A MORE RESOLVED VERSION OF THIS QUESTION, THINGS WHERE LEARNED HERE, AND THESE THINGS HAVE GREW TO NEW QUESTION [Issue Saving and Loading to/from File in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22879469/issue-saving-and-loading-to-from-file-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote it out myself in a separate program, and declared the codebook like so;
it works a charm, and answering nothing to why it isn't working in main program
I will continue hacking at it today. Thanks all.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Runner {

Map<Integer, String> decodebook = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
// List<Integer> numbers = new LinkedList<Integer>();
Map<String, List<Integer>> codebook = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();
List<Integer> numbers = new LinkedList<Integer>();
List<Integer> otherNumbers = new LinkedList<Integer>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    new Runner();
}

public Runner() throws IOException {
    /*
     * numbers.add(56); numbers.add(16); numbers.add(36); numbers.add(36);
     * numbers.add(66); numbers.add(6);
     * 
     * otherNumbers.add(68); otherNumbers.add(78); otherNumbers.add(28);
     * otherNumbers.add(668); otherNumbers.add(618); otherNumbers.add(686);
     * otherNumbers.add(682);
     * 
     * 
     * codebook.put("alf", numbers); codebook.put("tony", otherNumbers);
     * decodebook.put(7898, "alf"); decodebook.put(87576, "tony");
     */

    // saveStuff();
    loadBooks();
}

public void loadBooks() throws IOException {

    loadCodeBook("CodeBook");
    System.out.println(codebook);

    loadDeCodeBook("DecodeBook");
    // System.out.println(codebook);
    System.out.println(decodebook);

}

public Map<String, List<Integer>> loadCodeBook(String filePath)
        throws IOException {
    HashMap<String, List<Integer>> codebook = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filePath));
        codebook = (HashMap<String, List<Integer>>) ((ObjectInputStream) is)
                .readObject();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    } finally {
        is.close();
    }
    return this.codebook = codebook;
}

public Map<Integer, String> loadDeCodeBook(String filePath)
        throws IOException {
    HashMap<Integer, String> decodebook = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filePath));
        decodebook = (HashMap<Integer, String>) ((ObjectInputStream) is)
                .readObject();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    } finally {
        is.close();
    }
    return this.decodebook = decodebook;
}

/*
 * public void saveStuff(){ try { saveCodeBook(codebook, "CodeBook");
 * 
 * } catch (IOException e) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block
 * e.printStackTrace(); } try {
 * 
 * saveDecodeBook(decodebook, "DecodeBook"); } catch (IOException e) { //
 * TODO Auto-generated catch block e.printStackTrace(); }
 * 
 * }
 * 
 * public void saveCodeBook(Map<String, List<Integer>> obj, String filePath)
 * throws IOException { OutputStream os = null; try { os = new
 * ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath));
 * 
 * ((ObjectOutputStream) os).writeObject(obj); } catch (Exception ex) { }
 * finally { os.close(); } }
 * 
 * public void saveDecodeBook(Map<Integer,String> obj, String filePath)
 * throws IOException { OutputStream os = null; try { os = new
 * ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath));
 * 
 * ((ObjectOutputStream) os).writeObject(obj); } catch (Exception ex) { }
 * finally { os.close(); } }
 */

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems this the sublist method is to blame. In the full program, I populate the codebooks List with the use of subsisting from a "List keyOne = linkedlist.sublist" For some reason, when it is loaded this way it causes problems in saving. Even in example below this post I added this in the Runner() method.

```
codebook.put("tony", numbers.subList(0, 2));
codebook.put("alf", numbers.subList(3, 5));
```

instead of

```
codebook.put("alf", numbers);
codebook.put("tony", otherNumbers);
```

And when I use sublist I get back null.
Problem solved , only now a much bigger problem, sadly.