# Issue Saving and Loading to/from File in Java

Tags: java, file, dictionary, save, sublist

I have a similar question posted, it was getting messy and this will be much easier to follow. The part that is in the Runner() that is /*commented out*/. You un-comment this, run the program once, check you console print out. Then /*comment it out*/ again, and run the program a second time, you will notice that the subCodebook = {} is returning a blank/null; This is my question, why is this returning null.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Runner {

Map<Integer, String> decodebook = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
// List<Integer> numbers = new LinkedList<Integer>();
Map<String, List<Integer>> codebook = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();
Map<String, List<Integer>> subcodebook = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();
List<Integer> numbers = new LinkedList<Integer>();
List<Integer> otherNumbers = new LinkedList<Integer>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    new Runner();
}

public Runner() throws IOException  {

    /*numbers.add(6);
    numbers.add(156);
    numbers.add(363);
    numbers.add(336);
    numbers.add(26);
    numbers.add(61);

    otherNumbers.add(68);
    otherNumbers.add(78);
    otherNumbers.add(28);
    otherNumbers.add(668);
    otherNumbers.add(618);
    otherNumbers.add(686);
    otherNumbers.add(682);

    subcodebook.put("tony", numbers.subList(0, 2));
    subcodebook.put("alf", numbers.subList(3, 5));


    codebook.put("alf", numbers);
    codebook.put("tony", otherNumbers);
    decodebook.put(7898, "alf");
    decodebook.put(87576, "tony");

     saveStuff();*/


     loadBooks();
     System.out.println(" codebook" + codebook);
     System.out.println(" decodebook" + decodebook);
     System.out.println(" subCodebook" + subcodebook);
}

public void loadBooks() throws IOException {

     loadCodeBook("CodeBook");
    //System.out.println(codebook);

     loadsubCodeBook("subCodeBook");


     loadDeCodeBook("DecodeBook");
    // System.out.println(codebook);
    //System.out.println(decodebook);

}

public Map<String, List<Integer>> loadCodeBook(String filePath)
        throws IOException {
    HashMap<String, List<Integer>> codebook = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filePath));
        codebook = (HashMap<String, List<Integer>>) ((ObjectInputStream) is)
                .readObject();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    } finally {
        is.close();
    }
    return this.codebook = codebook;
}
public Map<String, List<Integer>> loadsubCodeBook(String filePath)
        throws IOException {
    HashMap<String, List<Integer>> subcodebook = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filePath));
        subcodebook = (HashMap<String, List<Integer>>) ((ObjectInputStream) is)
                .readObject();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    } finally {
        is.close();
    }
    return this.subcodebook = subcodebook;
}


public Map<Integer, String> loadDeCodeBook(String filePath)
        throws IOException {
    HashMap<Integer, String> decodebook = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filePath));
        decodebook = (HashMap<Integer, String>) ((ObjectInputStream) is)
                .readObject();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    } finally {
        is.close();
    }
    return this.decodebook = decodebook;
}

public void saveStuff() {
    try {
        saveCodeBook(codebook, "CodeBook");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {

        saveDecodeBook(decodebook, "DecodeBook");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {

        savesubCodeBook(subcodebook, "subcodeBook");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void saveCodeBook(Map<String, List<Integer>> obj, String filePath)
        throws IOException {
    OutputStream os = null;
    try {
        os = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath));

        ((ObjectOutputStream) os).writeObject(obj);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    } finally {
        os.close();
    }
}

public void savesubCodeBook(Map<String, List<Integer>> obj, String filePath)
        throws IOException {
    OutputStream os = null;
    try {
        os = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath));

        ((ObjectOutputStream) os).writeObject(obj);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    } finally {
        os.close();
    }
}

public void saveDecodeBook(Map<Integer, String> obj, String filePath)
        throws IOException {
    OutputStream os = null;
    try {
        os = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath));

        ((ObjectOutputStream) os).writeObject(obj);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    } finally {
        os.close();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You did not save and load the subCodebook.

Comment: @drkunibar I changed above code, and as expected, its now null, i was wondering why it wasn't returning null earlier. so now the print out is.                  codebook{alf=[6, 156, 363, 336, 26, 61], tony=[68, 78, 28, 668, 618, 686, 682]}
 decodebook{87576=tony, 7898=alf}
 subCodebooknull

Comment: OK - I see. Have a look at my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yout try to save (and restore) the same object twice. Try this an note `the important part`

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Runner {

    Map<Integer, String> decodebook = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
// List<Integer> numbers = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    Map<String, List<Integer>> codebook = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();
    Map<String, List<Integer>> subcodebook = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();
    List<Integer> numbers = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> otherNumbers = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new Runner();
    }

    public Runner() throws IOException {

        numbers.add(6);
        numbers.add(156);
        numbers.add(363);
        numbers.add(336);
        numbers.add(26);
        numbers.add(61);

        otherNumbers.add(68);
        otherNumbers.add(78);
        otherNumbers.add(28);
        otherNumbers.add(668);
        otherNumbers.add(618);
        otherNumbers.add(686);
        otherNumbers.add(682);

        // ---------------------------------------------------------
        //
        //  the imprtant part
        // 
        // ------------------------------------------------------------
        subcodebook.put("tony", new ArrayList(numbers.subList(0, 2)));
        subcodebook.put("alf", new ArrayList(numbers.subList(3, 5)));

        codebook.put("alf", numbers);
        codebook.put("tony", otherNumbers);
        decodebook.put(7898, "alf");
        decodebook.put(87576, "tony");

        saveStuff();
        System.out.println(" codebook" + codebook);
        System.out.println(" decodebook" + decodebook);
        System.out.println(" subCodebook" + subcodebook);
        loadBooks();
        System.out.println(" codebook" + codebook);
        System.out.println(" decodebook" + decodebook);
        System.out.println(" subCodebook" + subcodebook);
    }

    public void loadBooks() throws IOException {

        loadCodeBook("CodeBook");
        //System.out.println(codebook);

        loadsubCodeBook("subcodeBook");

        loadDeCodeBook("DecodeBook");
        // System.out.println(codebook);
        //System.out.println(decodebook);

    }

    public Map<String, List<Integer>> loadCodeBook(String filePath)
            throws IOException {
        HashMap<String, List<Integer>> codebook = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filePath));
            codebook = (HashMap<String, List<Integer>>) ((ObjectInputStream) is)
                    .readObject();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }
        return this.codebook = codebook;
    }

    public Map<String, List<Integer>> loadsubCodeBook(String filePath)
            throws IOException {
        HashMap<String, List<Integer>> subcodebook = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filePath));
            subcodebook = (HashMap<String, List<Integer>>) ((ObjectInputStream) is)
                    .readObject();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }
        return this.subcodebook = subcodebook;
    }

    public Map<Integer, String> loadDeCodeBook(String filePath)
            throws IOException {
        HashMap<Integer, String> decodebook = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filePath));
            decodebook = (HashMap<Integer, String>) ((ObjectInputStream) is)
                    .readObject();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }
        return this.decodebook = decodebook;
    }

    public void saveStuff() {
        try {
            saveCodeBook(codebook, "CodeBook");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {

            saveDecodeBook(decodebook, "DecodeBook");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {

            savesubCodeBook(subcodebook, "subcodeBook");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void saveCodeBook(Map<String, List<Integer>> obj, String filePath)
            throws IOException {
        OutputStream os = null;
        try {
            os = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath));

            ((ObjectOutputStream) os).writeObject(obj);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        } finally {
            os.close();
        }
    }

    public void savesubCodeBook(Map<String, List<Integer>> obj, String filePath)
            throws IOException {
        OutputStream os = null;
        try {
            os = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath));

            ((ObjectOutputStream) os).writeObject(obj);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        } finally {
            os.close();
        }
    }

    public void saveDecodeBook(Map<Integer, String> obj, String filePath)
            throws IOException {
        OutputStream os = null;
        try {
            os = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath));

            ((ObjectOutputStream) os).writeObject(obj);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        } finally {
            os.close();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: excellant, that works a treat, only that treat is a wolf in lambs clothing for the main program. lots of refactoring to be done. Still with your solution it has shown me it is not as bad as I first expected, I am sure I can resolve it with some refactoring, thanks

Comment: Enjoy - fine that I could help

Comment: It works a treat, thank you so much, I do love the fact one can get help here when stuck, that was a long process. Watching the program run was a joy, so thank you again.